# how to emulate print device with safari

Tags: html, css, printing, safari, media

Some of pages of our app has print functionality, print is working fine in firefox and chrome but it does not work on safari, I want to know is there any option in safari browser for debugging print styles?

Answer (score 15):

While in Safari, right click the page and go to Inspect Element. While on the Inspect Element tab, click the **printer** icon (near the top right corner of the tool) and that will force print style sheets.

Comment: This doesn't work that well, I have a page with a bootstrap card-column and when I go to print it, the cards are all one line each but when I use this method to attempt to emulate printing they look pretty much the same as on screen, not on print.